# .NET Bulk Insert MSSQL: Failed to Obtain column Collation Information on one Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, bulkinsert

I've implemented a bulk insert with my .NET application and it works on all installations except for one specific customer.

There is no file access in this bulk insert, the data being inserted is generated by the application.

They are receiving an error:

> Failed to Obtain Column Collation Information

There is a previous article that states that granting the VIEW DEFINITION worked for them, but that has not worked here.

In our troubleshooting we have set the user to sys_admin for the server and it still fails with the same error.

Are there any ideas as to what the issue could be?

Comment: Post the code and table schema, and the *actual* full error message if any. What article do you refer to? StackOverflow isn't a blog site, there are no articles here, only questions and answers

Comment: Add the versions you use too - .NET version, SQL Server version. Simply googling for that message returns several hits. In some of them, the problem was that the table names contained dots. SqlBulkCopy needs to retrieve the target table information to create mappings, check for type and collation mismatches, so it needs `VIEW DEFINITION` to retrieve that information. In some related cases, the code didn't specify the mappings explicitly and the source columns ended up mapping to the wrong target columns

Comment: You can check what's going on if you use Extended Events in all current SQL Server versions, or SQL Server Profiler in older unsupported versions, to check what calls are actually made and which fail